# call to DynamoDB from a lambda stops dead, not even an error

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I was testing some code. Locally it works. When I put it in a lambda it stops dead!

#### index.js

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const MyHandler = require("./handler.js");

// Initialise DynamoDB client outside of lambda for re-use
if (typeof docClient === 'undefined') {
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "eu-west-1"})
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    context.dynamoDbClient = docClient;

    await MyHandler.processEvent(event, context);
}
```

#### handler.js

```js
processEvent = (event, context) => {
    console.log("Message received");
    var params = {
        TableName: "TestTable",
        Item: {"test": "test"}
    };
    console.log("Inserting into dynamoDB");
    try {
        return context.dynamoDbClient.put(params, (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error: Unable to insert DynamoDB: " + error);
            } else {
                console.log("Inserted into dynamoDB");
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error inserting to dynamoDB: " + e);
    }
};
```

In the AWS logs, after `Message received` I get nothing other than a `END RequestId:...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `await` with a synchronous function `processEvent` - this will resolve immediately; not wait.

Lambda will 'kill' unresolved promises, or in your case a callback, as soon as your handler returns. Whatever you're testing with locally may not do that, so although your handler function has returned, the callback gets executed in that environment (speculation).

Your problem is that you're mixing callbacks with Promises incorrectly. The AWS SDK exposes a promise option for almost all calls, so I suggest using that rather than writing your own:

```js
processEvent = (event, context) => {
    var params = {
        TableName: "TestTable",
        Item: {"test": "test"}
    };
    return context.dynamoDbClient.put(params).promise()
};
```

Comment: I took out all async/await and handled the promise returned from processEvent. That did it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Another issue that can cause this**: in case you have attached your lambda to a VPC/Subnet, you must make sure that the subnet has a **Gateway Endpoint** (to dynamodb service) and there is a route that directs traffic to that endpoint.

otherwise lambda requests to dynamoDB will halt due to the reason that dynamo will never get the query requests.

Follow AWS docs on this matter:
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-ddb.html

**And if you use Terraform to deploy AWS service** you need something like this:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "dynamodb_endpoint" {
  vpc_id       = data.your_vpc.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${data.aws_region.current.name}.dynamodb"
  route_table_ids   = [for r in data.your_route_tables : r.id]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [VPC Connected Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html)

> By default, Lambda runs your functions in a secure VPC with access to AWS services and the internet. Lambda owns this VPC, which isn't connected to your account's default VPC. When you connect a function to a VPC in your account, the function can't access the internet unless your VPC provides access.

What this mean in practical terms is that if you selected "Enable VPC" when you created your Lambda you need to follow this [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-ddb.html) as @[Mercury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3263659/mercury) mentioned.

[image]

Otherwise, as long as you have not selected "Enable VPC" your Lambda function will run in its own VPC and your VPC configuration will be empty as shown below. In this case you will not need to create a VPC Gateway to DynamoDB and your function should connect to DynamoDB and run without issue.

[image]

Another issue is that when the DynamoDB connection is invoked the lambda hangs, produces no logs, and then times out. So the only info you get is that there was a timeout, which could be caused by a number of other problems. The DynamoDB connection may not be the issue so if your Lambda is still timing after adding the VPC Gateway try increasing the Lambda's memory or its timeout. Both can be done by editing the General Configuration.

[image]
[image]